# Array Duplicate Elimination with c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, nested, duplicates

I have a program here that need some improvements. This Program inputs 5 elements in an Array and Removes if any duplicates. It works but the problem is that it sets every duplicate to zero. I don't want to display zero. I want it completely destroyed and eliminated. I don't want that duplicate element to appear. This is what I have so Far! Could Use some help. Thank You.

```
// Gurpreet Singh
// Duplicate Program
using System;

class duplicate 
{
    static void Main() 
    {
    const int Array_Size = 5;
    int [] number = new int [Array_Size];
    int i;

    for ( i = 0; i < Array_Size; i++) 
    {
        Console.Write("Element " + i + ":    ");
        number[i] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (number[i] < 9 || number[i] > 101)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Number between 10 - 100");
            number[i] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < Array_Size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Array_Size; j++) 
        {
            if (i != j)
            {
                if (number[j] == number[i])
                    number[j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Duplicate Removed:");
    for (i = 0; i < Array_Size; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Element " + i + "    " + number[i]);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to use Linq's [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx) method:

```
number = number.Distinct().ToArray();
```

This will return a new array without any duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

The duplicate is displayed as zero, since you assign the value of the duplicate to be zero, in the line,

```
if(number[j]==number[i])
    number[j]=0
```

to delete the element from the array, use the following code:

```
if(number[j]==number[i])
{
    int k=j;
    while(k<Array_Size-1)
    {
        number[k]=number[k+1];
        k++;
    }
    Array_Size--;
}
```

the statement `Array_Size--;` is done so that the last element is not repeated twice

Answer (score 1):

This is my complete code in which I put some double-for-loop statement to
prevent it from inserting the duplicated integers in an array. 
Have a look.

```
 class Program
 {
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     const int ARRAY_SIZE = 5;
     int[] ArrayTable = new int[ARRAY_SIZE];
     int Element=0;
     int a;

     for(a=0; a<ArrayTable.Length;a++)
     {

        Console.Write("Please Enter an integer (between 10-100): ");
        Element = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        while (Element < 10 || Element > 100)
        {
           Console.Write("Try again (between 10-100): ");
           Element = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        ArrayTable[a] = Element;
        for (int b = 0; b < a; b++)
        {
           while (ArrayTable[a] == ArrayTable[b])
           {
              Console.Write("Integer Duplicated!\nTry again: ");
              Element = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
              ArrayTable[a] = Element;
              Console.WriteLine();
              while (Element < 10 || Element > 100)
              {
                 Console.Write("Try again (between 10-100): ");
                 Element = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                 ArrayTable[a] = Element;
              }
           }
        }
     }

     for (int c = 0; c < ArrayTable.Length; c++)
     {
        Console.Write("{0} ", ArrayTable[c]);
     }
  }
```